# Custom Attributes for customer

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, customer, customer-attribute

I want to add extra fields for customer (not on registration) where there should around 20 fields. We can do this easily in magento 1 but i didn't see any thing same in M2.

looking for guidance and if this can be achieved from admin that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This article describe it step by step:
http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html

The main part is DataInstall::install method:

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

```
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, '{attributeCode}', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => '{attributeLabel}',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'position' => 1000,
        'system' => 0,
    ]);
    //add attribute to attribute set
    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'magento_username')
    ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
    ]);

    $attribute->save();


}
```

Or a bit slighter:

```
$customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

$customerSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
    'nickname',
    [
        'label'            => 'Nickname',
        'required'         => 0,
        'system'           => 0,
        'position'         => 100
    ]
);

$customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'nickname')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer'])
    ->save();
```

Also here is nice article:
https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-attribute-programatically-magento2/

Comment: It mean option  M2 is missing adding customer attributes like M1. Thanks for your reply and  I am going to work on your response.

Comment: Yea, there is no option for create it from admin. let me know if it works for You:)